# How to replace all but last matching in a file using bash?

Tags: bash, replace

Assuming using **bash**, having a configuration file like:

> 1. param-a=aaaaaa
> 2. param-b=bbbbbb
> 3. **param-foo=first occurence <-- Replace**
> 4. param-c=cccccc
> 5. ***# param-foo=first commented foo <-- Commented: don't replace***
> 6. param-d=dddddd
> 7. param-e=eeeeee
> 8. **param-foo=second occurence <-- Rreplace**
> 9. **param-foo=third occurence <-- Last active: don't replace**
> 10. param-x=xxxxxx1
> 11. param-f=ffffff
> 12. ***# param-foo=second commented foo <-- Commented: don't replace***
> 13. param-x=xxxxxx2

In which you can find multiple commented or uncommented lines of the param-foo,
how can you comment all the uncommented param-foos except the very last active one,
resulting in:

> 1. param-a=aaaaaa
> 2. param-b=bbbbbb
> 3. **# param-foo=first occurence <-- Replaced**
> 4. param-c=cccccc
> 5. ***# param-foo=commented foo <-- Left***
> 6. param-d=dddddd
> 7. param-e=eeeeee
> 8. **# param-foo=second occurence <-- Replaced**
> 9. **param-foo=third occurence <-- Left**
> 10. param-x=xxxxxx1
> 11. param-f=ffffff
> 12. ***# param-foo=second commented foo <-- Left***
> 13. param-x=xxxxxx2

Two parts of the question:
1. How to do it with only one **known repeating** param?
(only param-foo in the example above)

2. How to do it with all multiple active params at once?

(param-foo + param-x in the example above)
**Attention: In this case I don't know previously the name of the repeating params!**

Thanks

Comment: do you always have spaces between # and the actual text?

Comment: I usually comment like this, but it can happen to another person to comment differently .. so the only sure thing is to have a commented line starting with #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If awk is acceptable, this will do it for *param-foo* and *param-x*:

```
awk -F= -v p='param-foo param-x'  'BEGIN { 
  ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC - 1]
  n = split(p, t, OFS)
  for (i = 0; ++i <= n;) _p[t[i]]
  }
NR == FNR {
    $1 in _p && nr[$1] = NR
  next
  }  
$1 in nr && FNR != nr[$1] {
  $0 = "# " $0 
  }1' infile
```

You may use a single parameter: *p=param-x* or add more parameters separated by spaces: *p='param-1 param-2 ... param-n'*.

Edit: I'm assuming the real input file looks like this:

```
param-a=aaaaaa
param-b=bbbbbb
param-foo=first occurence
param-c=cccccc
# param-foo=commented foo
param-d=dddddd
param-e=eeeeee
param-foo=second occurence
param-foo=third occurence
param-x=xxxxxx1
param-f=ffffff
param-x=xxxxxx2
```

Let me know if it's different.

Second edit: providing a solution for *mawk* users:

```
awk -F= -v p='param-foo param-x'  'BEGIN { 
  n = split(p, t, OFS)
  for (i = 0; ++i <= n;) _p[t[i]]
  }
NR == FNR {
    $1 in _p && nr[$1] = NR
  next
  }  
$1 in nr && FNR != nr[$1] {
  $0 = "# " $0 
  }1' infile infile
```

Adding solution for the latest requirement:

```
awk -F= 'NR == FNR {
  if (NF && !/^#/)
    _p[$1]++ && nr[$1] = NR
  next
  }    
$1 in nr && FNR != nr[$1] {
  FNR != nr[$1] && $0 = "# " $0 
  }1' infile infile
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like what I need. However it doesn't work for me. It doesn't display anything :(

Comment: Are the numbers at the beginning of the lines part of the real input file?

Comment: no .. sorry, maybe that's confusing you .. they were just there to indicate the line number. It's my first post, I'm doing my best :)

Comment: OK, I assumed they weren't part of the input, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Could you post a sample of the real file? What's your OS?

Comment: I'm using lubuntu 11.10, awk is installed and working (tried with another easier test) I will edit the remaining info inside your asnwer

Comment: OK, and the script doesn't produce any output? Try passing the file though dos2unix (`apt-get install tofordos` if the package is missing)

Comment: @tanoloco, the script doesn't work with *mawk* (which happens to be the default *awk* on *Ubuntu*, try installing *gawk*: `sudo apt-get install gawk`. In the mean time I'll try to understand why it doesn't work with *mawk*.

Comment: @tanoloco, I've added a solution which should work with *mawk*.

Comment: I see .. you changed a litte bit your code, but unluckily still doesn't work .. sorry :(

Comment: Did you specify the input file twice?

Comment: brilliant! It's working! I didn't noticed the infile was repeated twice! I might learn how to use awk, its syntax looks so complicated to me .. only one more little step, if it's possible: what if I don't know previously the name of multiple params? I mean: how to do it if I have a long conf file and I don't know which one of the param is repeated as active and how many of them? In my example I did know it but in real life I might don't know

Comment: @tanoloco, I've added it to the post.

Comment: Thank you for your further tip! It doesn't do what I meant, sure I express myself bad. However I could implement successfully your code by using your second edit (for mawk users) and passing to it a string on the first line like this **awk -F= -v p="$_repeated"  'BEGIN {** in which $_repeated is a string I previously create with a space separeted list of repeated params I found in the file. The way I do to get this string is a little bit complicated, sure there's another easier way to do it, but it works and after all I'm still a beginner :) I'll study awk I promise :)

Comment: @tanoloco, I believe all you need is the last version in my post (I've just added it): it automatically comments the repeating parameters, leaving out the latest ones.

Comment: Wow! That's really impressive! Duh, you really rock !!! I'm even more impressed because I can't understand awk syntax and all this looks like magic to me! Really many many thanks! You avoid me a lot of complicated staff with just a few lines!

Comment: If occasionally the config file contains empty lines between params your code will remove those empty lines shrinking the config file in a stange way. Try your "/etc/default/grub" just for test. Is it possible to keep those empty lines? I would to keep the config exactly like the original except for the replacements. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A bit slow for long files, but should work for all the parameters:

```
grep -v ^# $file |
cut -f1 -d= |
sort -u |
sed 's/^/grep -n . '$file' |
tac |
grep -m1 :/;s/$/= /' |
bash |
sed -r 's%([0-9]+):(.*)=(.*)%\1!s/^\2=/# \2=/%' |
sed -f- $file
```

Comment: thank you for your tip! however running your code here produces to loose some lines :( .. I edit your answer to show you

Comment: I cannot edit your answer .. anyhow only the last active line is shown, while any previous is removed, and so all commented lines are removed. And this is not what is expected to be, although your solution results interesting to me

Comment: I misread the specification, sorry. I edited the answer: it's now 1 line shorter and should work.

Comment: Hi, your code is still working "strange" here: the first occurrence of param-foo and param-x is not commented but removed and so the second one of param-foo, the first comment of param-foo is also removed. Finally the order of the lines is not maintained which is essential. Sorry :/

Comment: I reread the specification and edited the code. It is no longer short nor nice, but could work. Never mind...

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested fully the script, but it worked on the first example:

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file=/path/to/your/input/file    
last_occurence=`nl $input_file | grep 'param-foo' | grep -v '#' | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
sed -i '/#/!s/param-foo/# param-foo/g' $input_file
sed -i "${last_occurence}s/# param-foo/param-foo/" $input_file
```

It's very straight forward logic. First we get the last occurrence of param-foo, which is not commented. 
The first sed goes and comments all param-foo, which are not commented.
The second sed uses the line_number of last occurence of param-foo and removes the # character. You can easily wrap that in a function and use it inside a loop, providing a list of parameters, instead of only one.

Comment: Thank you for your input! It works perfectly! And except for the awk part I can understand what it does (I still never use awk and maybe this is why I couldn't figure this out by myself)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
param="param-foo"
tac input_file |sed '/#/!{/'"$param"'/{x;/./{x;s/'"$param"'/# &/;t};x;h;}}'|tac >output_file
```

For multiple params:

```
cp input_file{,.backup}
params=(param-{foo,bar,baz})
tac input_file >backwards_file
for param in "${params[@]}"; do
    sed -i '/#/!{/'"$param"'/{x;/./{x;s/'"$param"'/# &/;t};x;h;}}' backwards_file
done
tac backwards_file >output_file
```

Turn `input_file` backwards, preprend all but the first occurrence of `$param` with a comment `#`,then revert the file.

EDIT:
To extract the params from the file use this piece of code:

```
params=($(sed -rn '/^#/d;/^$/!s/^\s*([^=]*).*/\1/gp' input_file | sort | uniq))
```

Comment: Hello and thanks very much for your answer! I like very very much the solution you provided for a single param! Sure I'll use it. For multiple params I should express myself better: I don't know previously the name of the params repeated in the file. I'll edit my question to clarify this better. Of course I can do some check before over repeated params in the file and creatinf the array $params to pass to your script, but if you know how to do it more elegantly it would be great! Regards

Comment: Your solution for single param is excellent and I have successfully adopted it! :) Any idea how to fix your solution for multiple params in order to auto detect which are the repeating params?